# Fork GitHub to AzureDevOps?

Tags: git, github, azure-devops

[This 2014 post](http://www.woodcp.com/2014/01/how-to-fork-git-repositories-on-visual-studio-online/) indicates there was no native support for Forking from GitHub to AzureDevOps Git - a situation which does not seem to be changed. Is it still necessary to create a middleman to moderate changes from GitHub before pushing them into an AzureDevOps project? If so, does AzureDevOps Git Repo become the Origin? If so, can someone explain why?

Answer (score 18):

it is very simple,in AzureDevOps the project you want to clone the repository or create a new team project, click code tab. Click  repository menu in Code Tab (it is on the top left side) and select [Import repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops).

[image]

Pick the right SourceType GIT/TFVS
Add the URL probably your github repository URL (but it can be any)
if it is publicly accessible this is it,
otherwise Check  Requires authorization provide username, Password or PAT and Name the new repository in AzureDevOps and done.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to expand your answer to cover off the other details relating to pulling changes from the source repo into the VSTS repo?

Answer (score 4):

> Is it still necessary to create a middleman to moderate changes from GitHub before pushing them into a DevOps project

Yes, but you can import repository from GitHub directly. If there are some changes in GitHub, you need to refer to that article to push to DevOps git repository unless you import GitHub repository to new DevOps git repository (delete previous repository that created when import repository from GitHub)

> If so, does the DevOps Git Repo become the Origin?

No, the DevOps Git repository name won’t be changed. The Origin indicates the remote URL to Fetch and Push instead of the repository name (likes key-value). You also can add more than one, such as Origin2, Origin3.

> If so, can someone explain why?

Because there isn’t the feature to update DevOps Git repository from GitHub in DevOps.