# Forking Github repo with Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to fork a github repo to a self-hosted azure devops server and then be able to merge the original github repository into the forked one?
Additionally, if a fork already exists on github, is it possible to migrate it to azure, retaining all of its history?

Comment: Please note that the answer to "is it possible to..." is either "yes" or "no" (as far as I'm aware there's no reason that the answer wouldn't be "yes"). If you are experiencing a problem with doing what you're suggesting, please edit the question to specify that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fork GitHub to AzureDevOps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40752333/fork-github-to-azuredevops)

Comment: I knew I could import the repository, but I wasn't aware I could specify two remotes and merge from one to another (with some steps in between). It solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this issue,  we can import repository from GitHub directly.

Click repository menu in Code Tab and select `Import repository`:

[image]

Then, slect the SourceType GIT and add your github repository URL and requires authorization:

[image]

You can also refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58304219/forking-github-into-azuredevops) with the same issue.